# Is Microsoft's Windows 10 Pro Hyper-V VM any more preformant, or efficiant, than Oracle's Virtual Box VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I currently use VirtualBox by Oracle, but I found out recently that because I have **Windows 10: Professional Ed.** that I can use **Microsoft's VM: Hyper-V**. As it is a bit of a job setting up VMs, and its an especially grueling task having to move the software that I am currently developing & testing, from one VM, to the other VM. So before I do all that, I wanted to see if there performance benefit to using Microsoft's Hyper-V VM, over VirtualBox, or if its one of those situations where the VM I choose isn't going to make a difference in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Windows and Hyper-V are both created by Microsoft,
it's logical that Microsoft's implementation of Hyper-V is
better integrated with Windows.

As Virtualbox emulates virtual hardware, any hardware references
involves two calls: One to the virtual hardware driver, then by
Virtualbox to the real Windows driver.
For this reason Virtualbox cannot do good
pass-through access to the real hardware.

On the other hand, Hyper-V Generation 2 virtual machines employ
drivers that are only thin wrappers on the real hardware,
so with better performance.
For this reason, Hyper-V can do much better pass-through of real
hardware (if required).

So if your VM needs to much access the hardware, such as the disk
and other devices, Hyper-V will give better performance.
Otherwise, the two are equivalent, except that the user interface of
Virtualbox is somewhat easier to use.

For more information see the (somewhat old) article of
[Generation 2 Virtual Machine Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn282285(v=ws.11)).

Comment: Curently I am using a VM  just as the development branch for my tiny web-app — I SSH  to it from VSCode &/or ATOM, and when something is production ready I commit it to the trunk. I guess I'll just stick to using VirtualBox, as I already have a private & local development version deployed to a VirtualBox VM, after reading your answer, I don't see any reason for changing. Your answer was far more helpful than I could have hoped for, and for thank I thank you,